# Nested combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $A$ bags, each with $B$ red balls and $C$ black balls. I choose $D$ balls from each bag and put the selected balls into a separate "chosen balls" bag. After going through each bag, I then choose $E$ balls from the "chosen balls" bag. How do I calculate the probability of choosing an even number of red and black balls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter that there are $A$ bags, join them into one bag of $A(B+C)$ balls, $AB$ of which are red. Pick $AD$ balls. Calculate the probability of getting $R$ red balls among the $AD$. For each possible $R$, calculate the probability $P$ that, choosing $E$ from the $AD$ you get an equal number of red and black. Then $\sum \Pr(R)P$ gives the answer.

Comment: Interesting. Is this the same approach I would use if `D` is odd and I only put one ball out of the `D` balls into the "chosen balls" bag? (The ball to put in would the color which is in the majority of the `D` balls.) Or is this question better asked as a separate one?